# Cordova app ios and android platform suddenly restarts

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I start using the application without problems, but after a while playing with it, clicking around it hangs and shows a blank page for a second and then everything starts over again without console errors neither ios log errors nor crashes. I added some console.log into the onLoad method and deviceReady event and both are executed, also neither localStorage nor sessionStorage get cleared.
I'm using cordova 6.1.1 and cordova-ios 4.1.1 cordova-android 5.1.1 and AngularJS 1.5.5 base code, the plugins that I'm using are

[This is the memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjRUu.png)

- cordova-plugin-geolocation@2.1.0
- cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.1.0
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen@3.1.0
- cordova-plugin-network-information@1.2.0
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@1.3.0
- cordova-plugin-x-toast@2.4.2
- cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview@1.6.1
- cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine@~1.0.3
- cordova-plugin-facebook4@~1.7.1
- cordova-plugin-google-app-conversion-tracker
- cordova-labs-wkwebview-engine-localhost
- cordova-plugin-device
- cordova-plugin-file@~4.2.0
- cordova-plugin-file-transfer@~1.5.1

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: ios is a pain in the nethers, you will need to get a Mac if you are going to do any kind of debugging. And then jump through some more hoops to get the enviro setup..
For my Android / cordova enviroment, I can debug over USB straight on Chrome and see what is throwing errors from my Desktop. That is why I charge up to 200% more to publish to iOS if my clients need it..

Comment: Actually I'm debugging it but no errors just see the console showing the initial messages once it restarts.

Answer (score 0):

On Chrome or Webview playstore Upgrade the SYSTEM will kill the cordova app(With SystemWebViewClient and SystemWebChromeClient extends Webview) and relaunches it.Helps in getting new updates of webview to 3rd party Developers.

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview